# Can large HashMap lead to out of memory exception in Android?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-memory

I am maintaining a Map of around ~200 items. Can it lead to out of memory exception? Is it a good practice to store big data 200+ or 500+ items in a Map to avoid loading from network or Sqlite?

Also below is my app Heap Size, is it normal or taking much RAM?

[image]

Comment: Sqlite has a memory option - should be only marginally slower than a Hashmap

Comment: To answer your question in the title: yes.

Comment: @Henry Is it ok to have ~500 key-value pairs data in Map for displaying content or is it better to load from Database everytime. For should i use a Custom Map which can store only recent ~10 key-value pairs

Comment: That really depends on how much memory your keys and values use. But in general, memory on mobile devices is a scarce resource.

Comment: But at the same time 200 items is not *generally* that large unless you have really big objects.

Comment: @chrylis I am using the approach (Please validate if its right)-> Table consists of data with ID as primary key. While Displaying data check if Map contains this ID(Key) if yes then directly take data from Map else Read from Database and store in map for future use. Map is Map<String,List>

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid of OOM by useing HashMap, you can try [SparseArray](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) or [ArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html).

SparseArray:

> It is intended to be more memory efficient than using a HashMap to map Integers to Objects, both because it avoids auto-boxing keys and its data structure doesn't rely on an extra entry object for each mapping.

ArrayMap:

> ArrayMap is a generic key->value mapping data structure that is designed to be more memory efficient than a traditional HashMap